# Raspberry Pi python serial FT232 not receive 8bytes

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I FT232 module connected to the Raspberry Pi (with USB cable). I want to receive 8bytes (1 byte). On Windows, Terminal draws me correctly beats (eg. `00001011`). In the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import binascii

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)

while True:

str1 = ser.read(1)

if str1 == '':
    print ''
else:
    print bin(int(binascii.hexlify(str1),16))
```

returns only 2 bits at the end:
`0b11111100` ,
`0b11111101` ,
`0b11111110` ,
`0b11111111`

What am I doing wrong that draws me just 2bits at the end?

Below please find screen how to receive data on Windows:
http://mateok.ovh/windows.jpg
And on Raspberry Pi:
http://mateok.ovh/linux.jpg

I would like to get on the Raspberry Pi received data were the same.

**Edit:**
I was able to find a solution! It turned out that the reason is ... that the device had been connected before starting the Raspberry Pi! If they Disconnect and reconnect only when the Raspberry Pi starts - values are returned well! Maybe someone knows the cause of this? And how can I fix it? I do not want every time you re-connect the converter ..

Comment: while True: str1 = ser.read(1) not equal ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
where terminator or packet loop time (for waiting every message)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the code to what you suggest - unfortunately did not help (except that the screen scrolls really fast). Still, unfortunately, the module returns only four values (in hex is 'ff', 'fd', 'fc', 'fe').

Comment: I was able to find a solution! It turned out that the reason is ... that the device had been connected before starting the Raspberry Pi! If they Disconnect and reconnect only when the Raspberry Pi starts - values are returned well!
Maybe someone knows the cause of this? And how can I fix it? I do not want every time you re-connect the converter ..

Comment: you want a serial bridge ? Serial is toggle type communication. If try PC to PC connection need use terminator(ex. '\r\n' return and line feed). Check parity, data length and stop bit. 
`PI side add your user to dialout(for permission)`